# Restify + https module Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, restify

I'm trying actually to make a call to the google API inside the restify call. But I got two problems :

1 - Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

The code below return me this error and even after looking how to get rid off this error on google, i still dont find a way to solve this one.

```
routes
    .use(server)
    .set('/test', 'get', function(req, res, next) {

            var opts = {
                host: "maps.googleapis.com",
                port : 443,
                path: "/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=xxx"
            }

            var rsl;
            https.get(opts, function(res2) {
                res2.on('data', (d) => {
                    rsl = d.toString('utf8');
                    res.send(200, rsl);
                    return next();
                });
            }).on('error', (e) => {
                  console.error(e);
            });
})
```

2 - I dont really care for now for this one but that gonna be my next question. I ask throught the google API call to get the result in json but still I get a buffer and i dont know how to turn this one in json. If you have any idea, that's welcome !

Comment: `https` is defined where? Are you using `require('request')` or similar for that? At any rate the `res.send()` within the `data` event handler does not look good here. In all likelihood that even gets raised multiple times handling the request where you are presuming it's only once.

Comment: Hello Neil and thanks for your answer. I'm using the require('https');

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

`headers` should be part of the options to send headers with request.

```
var opts = {
             host: "maps.googleapis.com",
             port : 443,
             path: "/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=xxx",
            headers: {
        }
      }
```

> google API call to get the result in json but still I get a buffer

Google maps api documentation - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

A sample request that return the response in json format - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=dubai